# Magento2 - Insert category image inside catalog product list

Tags: magento2

I want to add category Image inside Catalog Product List. How to add ?

[image: like here the right top is the category image and the rest are products]

Comment: What is your actual plan? It always on that 5th Position only? and which category image is that one?

Comment: yep, it always in the same place, the category image is the list category image